# Editing Profile from HTML to MongoDB via Express / Node JS

Tags: html, node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm trying to build a web platform that where you can register and adapt your profile. However, I'm struggling with the editing part. Registration and Login are fine, but the rest gives an HTTP 500. 
So here's what I did:

```
User Scheme for Mongoose: 
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');


//enhanced userSchema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    user_id: Schema.ObjectId,
    username: {type :String, required : true, unique : true}, //serves as unique identifier
    password: {type : String, required: true},
    name: {type : String, required : true},
    surname: String,
    created_at : Date,
    updated_at : Date,
    skills: [{type : String}],
    lectures: [{type : String}],
    groups: [{type : String}] //todo: Change for later cross referencing with group schemes
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Followed by the Routing:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var auth = require("../controllers/AuthController.js");
var profile = require ("../controllers/ProfileController");

// restrict index for logged in user only
router.get('/', auth.home);

// route to register page
router.get('/register.html', auth.register);

// route for register action
router.post('/register.html', auth.doRegister);

// route to login page
router.get('/login.html', auth.login);

// route for login action
router.post('/login.html', auth.doLogin);

// route for logout action
router.get('/logout.html', auth.logout);

//route to profile
router.get('/profile.html', profile.goToProfile);

//route for changing profile
router.post('/profile.html', profile.changeProfile);


module.exports = router;
```

And the profileController

```
/**
 * Controller for editing the profile
 */

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passport = require("passport");
var User = require("../models/User");
var path = require('path');

//Change Name

var profileController = {};

//go to Profile
profileController.goToProfile = function (req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('login.html')), {user : req.user};
}

profileController.changeProfile= function (req, res){
    console.log("REQUEST: " + req.body.toString());
    if (req.body.surname.isEmpty()){

    }
    else {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, { $set: { surname: req.body.surname }}, { new: true }, function (err, User) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.toString());}
            res.alert('Changed surname');
            console.log('changed surname')
        });
    };
    if (req.body.name.isEmpty()){}
    else {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, { $set: { name: req.body.name }}, { new: true }, function (err, User) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.toString());}
            res.alert('Changed name');
            console.log('changed name')
        });

    };

    if (req.body.skills.length === 0){}
    else {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, { $set: { skills: req.body.skills }}, { new: true }, function (err, User) {
            console.log("Old Skills: " + User.skills.toString());
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.toString());}
            console.log("New skills: " + User.skills.toString());
            console.log('changed skills')
        });

    }
};

module.exports = profileController;
```

Which gets its data from this HTML form:

```
<!-- register container -->
<div class="container">
    <form role="form" action="profile.html" method="post" style="max-width: 300px;">
        <h2 class="form-heading">Your Profile</h2>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" />
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" />
        <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"/>
        <input type="text" name="skills[]" placeholder="Your skills" class="form-control"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm very sorry for my bad code quality. This resulted from a very long day of working on it, but I simply couldn't figure out (even with tutorials and stack overflow) what went wrong.

The result is a 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your PUT request? To update data, you need to use a PUT request. POST is for adding new entries.

Comment: Hi Alacritas, I already tried that. I changed the HTML method from "post" to "put" and the `router.post('/profile.html', profile.changeProfile)` to `router.put(XXX)`. This didn't work unfortunately. I read in a post that HTML is not able to use the put method in forms. Is that still the case?